# Stopping a function (Python)

Tags: python, function, command

I tried searching online, but I didn't find anything relevant. Basically, what I'm looking for is a way to stop a function from continuing once a certain condition is met. I re-formatted most of a program that was supposed to only run once, which used sys.exit() before, into a function, but using sys.exit() messes up my loops.

Comment: Why not `return` from the function?

Comment: You could help yourself by going to python.org tutorial and find the part about functions, and specifically return

Answer (score 2):

Use `return` to exit to the caller:

```
def func(*args):
    while True:
        # Arbitrary code.
        if condition:
            return
```